# Проблема в подключений Objective-C к базе данных MySQL

Tags: mysql, objective-c

Как подключиться в Objective C к MySQL?

Вот те действия которые делаю для того чтобы работать с MySQL:

1. Установил сервер MAMP (Установка прошла успешно);
2. Создал Базу Данных в phpMyAdmin (на жестком диске в директорий MAMP в папке htdocs создал файл.php для соединение с созданной базой и внесение данных с помощью INSERT INTO Atendimento VALUES (…..));
3. Создал в Xcode проект в котором содержит пять TextField, одну кнопку и label;
   Результат: Проект запускает отлично без ошибок, ввожу данные в поля  и нажимаю на кнопку чтобы внести данные в таблицу, но ничего не происходит.

Не могу понять причину почему не вносится в базу данных MySQL.

Вот действие кнопки:

```
- (IBAction)inserir:(id)sender {

    NSMutableString *strURL = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://localhost/nsersAtendimento.php?nomeFunc=%@&nomeCt=%@telefone=%@problema=%@solucao=%@",
                               self.textFuncionari.text,
                               self.textClient.text,
                               self.textTelephone.text,
                               self.textInformation.text,
                               self.textQual.text];

    [strURL  setString:[strURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

    NSMutableString *strResult = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithData:dataURL
                                                              encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    self.textResultat.text = strResult;

}
```

Содержание файла.php:

```
<?php

$usuarion = "root";
$senha = "root";
$host = "localhost";

$database = "tutoriaisdb";

mysql_connect($host,$usuario,$senha) or die ("Error na conedo");

mysql_select_db($database) or die ("Error na selectionar banco");

$nomeFunc = $_GET["nomeFunc"];
$nomeCt = $_GET["nomeCt"];
$telefone = $_GET["telefone"];
$problema = $_GET["problema"];
$solucao = $_GET["solucao"];

$query = "INSERT INTO Atendimento VALUES ('','$nomeFunc','$nomeCt','$telefone','$problema','$solucao')";

mysql_query($query) or die ("Erro no inserir dadano");

echo "Attensimento inserido com sucesso";

mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: на всякий случай: у вас '&' пропущен между всеми параметрами после второго

Comment: у меня ваш код работает (с небольшими правками). что у вас в strResult и отладчике?

Comment: Max Mikheyenko спасибо за замечание.

Comment: Rapax у меня в strResult и в отладчике ничего не показывает, а какие ты делал исправления?

Comment: странно что не показывает. попробуй добавить в php файл echo "start!"; в самом начале кода. если и после этого strResult пуст - значит файл php просто не находится и не отрабатывает. возможная причина - не указан порт, на котором запущен Apache. у меня порт 8080, соот. нужно добавлять везде localhost:8080

Comment: Порты можно просмотреть в настройках MAMP, вкладка Ports. да, также я бы добавил в код NSLog(@"result=%@",strResult); чтобы точно быть уверенным, что результат возвращается действительно пустой.

Comment: Добавил в php файл echo "start!"; и  изменил порт в Apache на 8080, к сожалению результат ни каких изменение не произошло strResult пустой, даже с NSLog(@"result=%@",strResult);

Comment: после изменения порта, сделал рестарт апача? если отладчик пишет 'result=' (пусто) - php файл не выполняется. это и есть результат, теперь надо установить почему не выполняется. можешь выслать проект на rapax@list.ru ? в коде какая-то мелкая ошибка или дело в порте все-таки.

Comment: Да, я делал рестарт, когда поменял порт. Выслал проект на почту  rapax@list.ru

Comment: получил. код у меня отрабатывает без ошибок. в таблицу данные добавляются. очевидно, проблема в MAMP и его настройках.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь Rapax к сожалению сборка XMAPP не помогла решить проблему(, если нету антивирусных служб то какие могут сетевые службы препятствовать с соединению с базой?

Comment: 1. Во первых попробуйте выполнить запрос просто в браузере (в адресной строке) - так вы убедитесь что ваш php скрипт корректно работает и соединение с базой данных тоже происходит.
2. Во вторых вместо прямого запроса используйте AFNetworking через pod. Это позволит удобно получить ответ от вашего скрипта при возникновении ошибки на стороне сервера. Разумеется это можно сделать и без это библиотеки, но с ней сильно проще.